# Eu posso colocar o menu de navegação dentro do cabeçalho do site?

Tags: html5

Eu poderia colocar o menu de navegação dentro do cabeçalho do site? Normalmente, ele vem depois do cabeçalho (pelo que vi). Se eu colocar dentro, está errado? Eu fiz um site, depois que vi que o nav tava dentro do header.

Comment: Isso é baseado em opiniões mas não tem nada de errado ai, só mantenha o layout organizado de maneira que você identifique facilmente a navegação no header da página

Comment: lembre-se que antes do `HTML5`, não existiam tags semânticas como `nav` e `header`. Elas do ponto de vista de comportamento "não fazem nada", diferente de `a`, `img` ou `p`, por isso sua função é organizar o layout, sua função semântica é colocar as coisas no seu lugar. Então algo estranho seria o rodapé dentro do cabeçalho, ou `header` dentro de `aside`.

Comment: Só um comentário, na verdade vc pode ter vários footers na página, pois eles são relacionados aos elementos em que estão dentro. Então vc pode ter um footer por sessão por exemplo. Outra coisa interessante. Vc tb pode tem navs e headings dentro do footer!

Comment: Verdade @hugocsl, se pensar na semântica do `footer` ele é um rodapé, não pensamos nele como "rodapé da página", então pode ser o rodapé de qualquer coisa, página, um painel qualquer, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para responder sua pergunta de uma maneira mais assertiva e menos pautada em opiniões, peguei a referência do **W3C** sobre a tag `nav`: http://w3c.github.io/html/sections.html#the-nav-element

Em tradução livre:

> O elemento nav representa uma seção de uma página que se vincula a
>   outras páginas ou a outras partes da página: uma seção com links de
>   navegação.

Ou seja, deve ter a navegação em si, que pode ser no topo, lateral, etc.

E para tirar qualquer dúvida se ainda tiver, veja no mesmo link acima o **Exemplo 10**, copiado aqui a parte relevante:

```
<header>
    <h1>Wake up sheeple!</h1>
    <p><a href="news.html">News</a> -
      <a href="blog.html">Blog</a> -
      <a href="forums.html">Forums</a></p>
    <p>Last Modified: <span property="schema:dateModified">2009-04-01</span></p>
    <nav>
      <h2>Navigation</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="articles.html">Index of all articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="today.html">Things sheeple need to wake up for today</a></li>
        <li><a href="successes.html">Sheeple we have managed to wake</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Ou seja, navegação dentro do cabeçalho, nada de errado aqui, as tags semânticas `header` e `nav` trabalham bem juntas, mostram exatamente o que cada parte do `html` faz.

Comment: +1 pela ênfase no uso das tags semânticas do HTML5.